# In Angular 9, can I store a property in a place where all components can reference?

Tags: service, field, angular9

I'm using Angular 9.  I have this in most of my components' ...

```
import { DeviceDetectorService } from 'ngx-device-detector';
...

export class FirstComponent implements OnChanges, OnInit {
    ...

  isMobile: boolean = false;

  constructor(private deviceService: DeviceDetectorService) { }

  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.isMobile = this.deviceService.isMobile();
  }
```

and then in the components themselves I have

```
<mat-table *ngIf="isMobile" #table [dataSource]="dataSource">
...
</mat-table>

<mat-table *ngIf="!isMobile" #table [dataSource]="dataSource">
...
</mat-table>
```

My question is, is there a more efficient way of doing this, in other words, can I place the "isMobile" property in one place and have all my components reference that place instead of defining it in each of my components?